# get formatted_address from google maps api json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-maps, geocoding

I want to get the formatted_adress from the json array.
an example link could be http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=55.397563, 10.39870099999996&sensor=false

```
var url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="+latlng+"&sensor=false";
                $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
                    var adress = data['formatted_address'];
                    alert(adress);
                });
```

but im getting "undefined"

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here's the corrected JS..

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NNuDe/)

```
var latlng = "55.397563, 10.39870099999996";
var url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" + latlng + "&sensor=false";
$.getJSON(url, function (data) {
    for(var i=0;i<data.results.length;i++) {
        var adress = data.results[i].formatted_address;
        alert(adress);
    }
});
```

Comment: thank you, this solved my problem, ill accpect the answer in 4mins.

Comment: Thanks for this.. Just added to my code and worked perfectly!

Comment: Is there a rule on how much is the length of formatted_address if I want to get specific address format?

Comment: @Toniq not sure about the current version of api. You should check out latest documentation.

Answer (score 4):

```
data["results"][0]["formatted_address"]
```