# i want to use google API in my app where i insert any keyword so it must autocompete and gives me the city address

Tags: android

i want to use google api when i enter keyword it must give me city names with that keyword i want to use this by using StartActivityForResult()
     here is my code i have reached so far: but i don't know what to do next, i have the api key and i have used the key in my manifest file i just want to complete the coding part!

```
case R.id.linearPlace:{ startActivityForResult(new Intent(this,Location.class),CITY);

            }break;
        }
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestcode,int resultcode,Intent intent ){
        super.onActivityResult(requestcode,resultcode,intent);
        String geoName = intent.getStringExtra("");
    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19398702/get-formatted-address-from-google-maps-api-json

Answer (score 0):

here i am putting my code for simple search address on edittext change event

Layout File : activity_demo.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    tools:context="com.skandinaviske.elevkalender.DemoActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/actLocation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="Key word" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edtCountryCode"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="Country Name" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lstAddress"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout2"></ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Class File : DemoActivity.java

```
package com.demo.pack;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.VolleyLog;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class DemoActivity extends Activity {
    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    private EditText actLocation;
    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> listofAddress;
    private ListView lstAddress;
    private EditText edtCountryCode;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_demo);
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        actLocation = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.actLocation);
        edtCountryCode = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtCountryCode);
        lstAddress = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstAddress);
        actLocation.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if (actLocation.getText().toString().length() > 3) {
                    String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + actLocation.getText().toString().trim() + "%20" + edtCountryCode.getText().toString() + "&key=API_KEY&language=en_us";
                    fetchJsonResponse(url);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void fetchJsonResponse(String s) {
        // Pass second argument as "null" for GET requests
        JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(s, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        //String result = "Your IP Address is " + response.getString("ip");
                        Log.d("response==>", response.toString());
                        calldisplayList(response);
                        //Toast.makeText(EditProfileActivity.this, response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.e("Error: ", error.getMessage() + "");
            }
        });

        /* Add your Requests to the RequestQueue to execute */
        mRequestQueue.add(req);
    }

    private void calldisplayList(JSONObject response) {
        String city = "", state = "", country = "";
        if (response != null) {
            try {
                if (response.getString("status").toString().equals("OK")) {
                    JSONArray adddressArray = response.getJSONArray("results");
                    if (adddressArray.length() != 0) {
                        if (listofAddress == null) {
                            listofAddress = new ArrayList<>();
                        }
                        listofAddress.clear();
                        for (int i = 0; i < adddressArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = adddressArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
                            hashMap.put("address", jsonObject.getString("formatted_address").toString());
                            listofAddress.add(hashMap);
                        }
                        if (listofAddress.size() != 0 && actLocation.getText().length() != 0) {
                            AddressListAdapter addressListAdapter = new AddressListAdapter(DemoActivity.this, listofAddress);
                            lstAddress.setAdapter(addressListAdapter);
                            lstAddress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        } else {
                            lstAddress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    } else {

                    }
                } else {

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {

        }
    }

    public class AddressListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private final Activity context;
        private final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> listOfAddress;

        private class ViewHolder {
            TextView txtAddress;
        }

        public AddressListAdapter(Activity context1, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> listOfAddress) {
            this.context = context1;
            this.listOfAddress = listOfAddress;
        }


        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return listOfAddress.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return listOfAddress.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder viewHolder;
            View converView = view;
            if (converView == null) {
                LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                converView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.address_list_item, null);
                viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                viewHolder.txtAddress = (TextView) converView.findViewById(R.id.txtAddress);
                converView.setTag(viewHolder);
            } else {
                viewHolder = (ViewHolder) converView.getTag();
            }
            viewHolder.txtAddress.setText(listOfAddress.get(position).get("address") + "");

            return converView;
        }
    }

}
```

Layout File for Adapter : address_list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtAddress"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:text="temp data"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Don't miss to put API_KEY (Hear is the url from where you can get API key : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/get-api-key#get-an-api-key )

Comment: can you please provide me a demo code like how should i call this URL ? i am new and never used google API ever

Comment: please say your doubt.

Comment: this is my doubt! can you please help ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36012599/inherit-navigation-drawer-in-all-activities